# Don't run servlet with websocket in Coldfusion 9 and error 1006 javascript

Tags: javascript, servlets, iis, coldfusion, websocket

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Multiple file uploader</title>
    <script>
        var totalFileLength, totalUploaded, fileCount, filesUploaded;
        var startTime;
        var speed = 0;

        function debug(s) {
            var debug = document.getElementById('debug');
            if (debug) {
                debug.innerHTML = debug.innerHTML + '<br/>' + s;
            }
        }

        function onUploadComplete(e) {
            totalUploaded += document.getElementById('files').
                    files[filesUploaded].size;
            filesUploaded++;
            debug('complete ' + filesUploaded + " of " + fileCount);
            debug('totalUploaded: ' + totalUploaded);
            if (filesUploaded < fileCount) {
                uploadNext();
            } else {
                document.getElementById('form1').reset();
                document.getElementById('selectedFiles').innerHTML = "";
                alert('Finished uploading file(s): ' + event.target.responseText);
            }
        }

        function onFileSelect(e) {
            var files = e.target.files; // FileList object
            var output = [];
            fileCount = files.length;
            totalFileLength = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < fileCount; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                output.push(file.name, ' (',
                        file.size, ' bytes, ',
                        file.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString(), ')'
                        );
                output.push('<br/>');
                debug('add ' + file.size);
                totalFileLength += file.size;
            }
            document.getElementById('selectedFiles').innerHTML =
                    output.join('');
            debug('totalFileLength:' + totalFileLength);
        }

        function onUploadProgress(e) {
            if (e.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = parseInt(
                        (e.loaded + totalUploaded) * 100
                        / totalFileLength);
                var bar = document.getElementById('bar');
                bar.style.width = percentComplete + '%';
                bar.innerHTML = percentComplete + ' % complete';
            } else {
                debug('unable to compute');
            }
        }

        function onUploadFailed(e) {
            alert("Error uploading file:" + e);
        }

        function uploadNext() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var fd = new FormData();
            var file = document.getElementById('files').files[filesUploaded];
            fd.append('media', file);
            //xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", onUploadProgress, false);
            xhr.addEventListener("load", onUploadComplete, false);
            xhr.addEventListener("error", onUploadFailed, false);
            debug('uploading ' + file.name);
            xhr.open('POST', 'UploadFileServlet', true);
            xhr.send(fd);
        }

        function startUpload() {
            startTime = now();
            totalUploaded = filesUploaded = 0;
            uploadNext();
        }
        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('files').addEventListener(
                    'change', onFileSelect, false);
            document.getElementById('uploadButton').
                    addEventListener('click', startUpload, false);
        }

        //var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9966/status_socket");
        var socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + location.hostname + ":" + location.port + "/status_socket");
        socket.onopen = function() {
            //alert("Connection established.");
        };

        socket.onclose = function(event) {
            if (event.wasClean) {                   
            } else {
                alert('Connection terminated'); 
            }
            alert('Code: ' + event.code + ' reason: ' + event.reason);
        };

        socket.onmessage = function(e) {

            var endTime = now();
            var diff = endTime - startTime;
            var transferred = parseInt(e.data);
            if (diff > 0 && transferred > 0) {
                speed = transferred / diff * 100;
            }
            startTime = diff;

            var secondsLeft = parseInt((totalFileLength - transferred - totalUploaded) / speed);

            var date = new Date(null);
            date.setSeconds(secondsLeft);
            var timeLeft = date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);

            var percentComplete = parseInt((transferred + totalUploaded) * 100 / totalFileLength);
            var bar = document.getElementById('bar');
            var progressBar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
            var progressText = document.getElementById('progressText');

            //bar.innerHTML = percentComplete + ' % complete' + ', time left: ' + timeLeft + ' sec';
            //bar.style.width = percentComplete + '%';

            progressBar.value = percentComplete;
            //progressBar.innerHTML = percentComplete + ' % complete' + ', time left: ' + timeLeft + ' sec';
            progressText.textContent = percentComplete + ' % complete' + ', time left: ' + timeLeft;
            //alert("Получены данные " + e.data);
        };

        socket.onerror = function(error) {
            alert("Error " + error.message);
        };

        var now = (function() {

            // Returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since either the browser navigationStart event or
            // the UNIX epoch, depending on availability.
            // Where the browser supports 'performance' we use that as it is more accurate (microsoeconds
            // will be returned in the fractional part) and more reliable as it does not rely on the system time.
            // Where 'performance' is not available, we will fall back to Date().getTime().

            var performance = window.performance || {};

            performance.now = (function() {
                return performance.now    ||
                        performance.webkitNow     ||
                        performance.msNow         ||
                        performance.oNow          ||
                        performance.mozNow        ||
                        function() { return new Date().getTime(); };
            })();

            return performance.now();

        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>        
    <h1>Multiple file uploader</h1>
    <!--
    <div id='progressBar' style='height:20px;border:2px solid green'>
        <div id='bar' 
             style='height:100%;background:#33dd33;width:0%'>
        </div>
    </div> -->
    <span id="progressText"></span>
    <progress id='progressBar' style='width:100%;height:20px;' max="100" value="0"><span>Урраааааа</span></progress>
    <form id='form1' action="UploadFileServlet" 
          enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">    
        <input type="file" id="files" multiple/>
        <br/>
        <output id="selectedFiles"></output>
        <input id="uploadButton" type="button" value="Upload"/>
    </form>
    <div id='debug' 
         style='height:100px;border:2px solid green;overflow:auto'>
    </div>
</body>
```

I need to upload file on IIS 7+Coldfusion 9, which upload file to framesocket.com,who use servlet and websocket, but I see "Connection terminated", "Error 1006".I saw, what this servlet run perfect on Tomcat 8.09. But when I run it on IIS+Coldfusion-it is not works. Deal is in Coldfusion 9+Webspcket? Thank's for any help

Comment: I dunno a great deal about web sockets (other than proof of concept), but by the sounds of this blog article - http://forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2010/9/20/New-ColdFusion-WebSocket-Gateway-Released - you need something not "out of the box" running on CF9 for web sockets to work. Bear in mind CF9 doesn't - by default - run on Tomcat, it's JRun. So your tests to something running on TOmcat aren't necessarily meaningful. Sorry can't be much help beyond that.